# How to verify the image is present or not in protractor?

Tags: protractor

Here is HTML code:

```
<img ng-src="/static/images/Shine_small.jpg" width="32px" height="32px" src="/static/images/Shine_small.jpg">
```

Here is my code:

```
expect(element(by.binding('/static/images/Shine_small.jpg')).getAttribute('src'))
  .toMatch(/static/images/Shine_small.jpg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTMLImageElement read-only attribute `complete` ([w3c spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-img-element.html#dom-img-complete))

Just watch out to test if src **is not** empty as it will resolve to `complete` being true as well. You could use `browser.wait` to wait for it for a tolerated time to become `complete`.

Comment: just use `.getAttribute('complete')` and you need to test if it's `true`

Comment: I tried and am getting this error : Failed: No element found using locator: by.binding("/static/images/Shine_small.jpg")

Comment: Here is my code :  expect(element(by.binding('/static/images/Shine_small.jpg')).getAttribute('complete')).toBe(true);

Comment: don't know the structure of your code - if it says it can't find the element you need to fix your elementLocator (`by.something`) and make sure that you test the right element.

Comment: Here is HTML code :                                                                                      <img ng-src="/static/images/Shine_small.jpg" width="32px" height="32px" src="/static/images/Shine_small.jpg">

Comment: I tried with css, binding and  Xpath still am not able to verify.Please guide me

Comment: try doing by.css('img') or use more specific selector to avoid selecting wrong img if you have multiple on the page.  if it can't find any images and especially the one you want you must have a bigger issue here and probably html is not what you expect it to be, try to go over the protractor docs/tutorial cause stack overflow is not a place to learn everything and have things done for you but to solve more rare problems and to get a push in the right direction if stuck so please put some effort to sort it out You have the tool to make the test you need to write at hand - go and do it :) best

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111832/discussion-between-raghavendra-t-and-tom-tu).

Answer (score 1):

Use isDisplayed function. In your case it should be like below.

```
expect(element(by.binding('/static/images/Shine_small.jpg'))
       .isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible) {
              if(isVisible)     
              {
                expect(element(by.binding('/static/images/Shine_small.jpg')).getAttribute('src')) 
                .toMatch(/static/images/Shine_small.jpg);
             }
    });
```

Comment: I tried and am getting this error :  Failed: expect(...).isDisplayed is not a function

Comment: can you try with by.css

Answer (score 0):

try below piece of code...

```
it('should display image',()=>{
          element(by.css("img[src='./assets/images/circular.png']"))
        });
```

src is same as that of given to "img" in html